# Shipping rates if the customer chnages address in Paypal web

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal

I have question that if a customer changes the shipping address when he makes the payment in Paypal (Paypal IPN ,Paypal express) from the entered address(in our merchant website) , how can we do add the extra values or decrease the amount based on the new  shipping address .
Thanks
Az

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- [Implement the Instant Update API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/), or;
- Obtain shipping data by calling `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` [as described in this flow (#5)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/).

Hth...